# own application use zigbee2mqtt and homeassistant : concurrent access

Tags: zigbee, home-assistant

I have my own application. This application use the zigbee2mqtt service running on the server.

I want to add homeassistant on the same server.

The server is a Raspberry with a zigbee USB stick connected.

However, it seems that using both in the same time doesn't work.

Either it works for my application, either it works for home assistant.

Someone has an idea how to deal with it ?
Does I need to buy an other zigbee USB stick (one for my own application, and one for Home assistant ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution found is the following :

Use the homeassistant (supervisor) to have the feature to add the zigbee2mqtt add-on ([here](https://github.com/zigbee2mqtt/hassio-zigbee2mqtt/blob/master/README.md)).

Once it's successfully configured, the zigbee2mqtt service run in home assistant.

And you can send mqtt messages to the service from homeassistant (via the existing integration). Also, you can send mqtt messages from my own application.

It works !